# PHP inherit method which return $this;

Tags: php, oop

I am searching for the correct way to the next code in PHP:

```
class X {
    var $A = array();

    function Y() {
        $this->A[] = array('price'=>1);
        return $this;
    }
}

class Y extends X {

    var $VAT = 1.27;

    function Y() {

        parent::Y(); //at this point what is the correct way to call parent method?

        foreach ($this->A AS $akey => $aval) {
            if (is_array($aval)&&(array_key_exists('price',$aval))) {
                $this->A[$akey]['price'] = $aval['price'] * $this->VAT;
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

When I call parent method with "parent::Y();" I think this will not the correct way in PHP because it will return with an object which not ordered to any variable identifier and may cause a warning or a notice in error log.

Have anybody a good advice for what is the correct way to call method in this situation - Without modifying class X?

Comment: What do you mean `Without modifying class A?`? Where is class `A` in this code? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: The class A is in a framework core code and I don't want to modify it directly. I would like to extending the original code with my own logic.

Comment: There's still no `A` class in that code. I see only class `X` and class `Y`, `$A` is array

Comment: Sorry, that was my fault, I misstyped. The correct is the class X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to call parent method you can simply do it without a problem using `parent::method_name()`.

As in this case `$A` property is public (`var` used) it will be visible also in child class.

You don't need to worry that method `Y` returns `$this`. It's used probably for chaining class methods and you don't use it here so you don't need to care about it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as [the official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php) goes, `parent::method();` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The method is fine as it is. No need to assign the result of `parent::Y()` to a variable.